# Disable add of related record in Django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I would like to customize a Django 5+ admin view page. The model looks like this

```py
class Person
    tutor = models.ForeignKey("Person", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

and consequently the edit page for `Person` has a drop down box to select from a list of already added persons to the database, and `add` and `delete` buttons. Is there a way to remove (or disable) these `add` and `delete` buttons so that only Persons added before can be selected used? But I do not want to disable adding Persons in general, I just want that it cannot be done through this button.